# Moment.js not properly calculating the weeks between two dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have set 2 moments, the birth_date var is a moment equialing to (1997-12-08) (YYYY-MM-DD) , and the death_Date is a moment equaling to (2097-12-08) (YYY-MM-DD)

```
//returns the weeks to live between death and birth date, rounded to upper week

var weeks_to_live = moment(death_date).diff(moment(birth_date), 'days') / 7;
console.log("semanas a vivir: " + Math.ceil(weeks_to_live))
return Math.ceil(weeks_to_live);
```

This operation returns 5218 weeks
While google and almost any online calculator says that 100 years have 5214 weeks.

Why is there suach a difference?

**EDIT**: Found other onine caculators which return my result
Who is right then?

Comment: Maybe leap days of leap years are considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because of leap years:

```
> (new Date('2097-12-08') - new Date('1997-12-08')) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)
36525
```

That number is basically how many days are between those two dates: their difference in milliseconds divided by milli (1000) * seconds in hour (3600) * hours in day (24).

As you can see, there's quite a bit of 'discrepancy' between this number and 36500 (100 * 365) - 25 days, to be precise. And yes, those 25 days are what makes up the difference of ~4 weeks.